HTML Text within section not going to new line
I am trying to add the main part of my html page but whenever I add new elements, they just stay on the same line instead of continuing onto a new line.
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PunjabiImprov</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <main class="word">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Word of the day</h1>
        </div>
        
        <section class="WordCard">
            <h1>Punjabi Word</h1>
            <p>Click to check the definition</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>`

`*{
    background-color:#1a1b1e;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.word {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: wrap;
}`



white-space: wrap; - Do you mean flex-wrap: wrap?

Add flex-direction: column

Try changing the flex-direction property to column. See updated css below;
* {
    background-color: #1a1b1e;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.word {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  /* Add this line */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   
}

Hope that helps :)
